# How to make a computationally expensive row-wise operation into efficient vectorized one?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Fellow contributors,
I have written a program that is meant to be applied on a data set of more than a million observations. At some point of the program I need to do row-wise operations on a pandas data frame where considering the number of observations it could take a while to be executed. I would like to find a more efficient way of doing it in particular if there is an efficient vectorized way to do it as we would do in the same situation in R. Here is a sample data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
                   'B' : ['Blue', 'Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue']})
```

And my code (However in real code there are more if-else expressions to be checked):

```
def my_fun(row):
    if (row['A'] == 'Yes') & (row['B'] == 'Blue'):
        return 'foo'
    elif (row['A'] == 'Yes') & (row['B'] == 'Red'):
        return 'bar'
    else:
        return 'foobar'

    return row

df['C'] = df.apply(my_fun, axis = 1)
```

Which results in:

```
df
     A     B       C
0  Yes  Blue     foo
1   No   Red  foobar
2  Yes   Red     bar
3  Yes  Blue     foo
4   No  Blue  foobar
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.select`

```py
df['D'] = np.select(
    [df['A'].eq('Yes') & df['B'].eq('Blue'),
     df['A'].eq('Yes') & df['B'].eq('Red')],
    ['foo', 'bar'],
    'foobar'
)
```

```
print(df)

     A     B       C       D
0  Yes  Blue     foo     foo
1   No   Red  foobar  foobar
2  Yes   Red     bar     bar
3  Yes  Blue     foo     foo
4   No  Blue  foobar  foobar
```

Comment: It is interesting that we first specify the conditions and the choices as 2 arguments that should be of the same length. Can we use it for nested if-else clause as well?

Comment: Also I would like to know can we create a numpy array and use it as a pandas series in a data frame in such a way that we use it as a column?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Don't know what do you mean by nested if-else clause, but use Series in if-else is syntax not allowed. You can assign a numpy array that is the same length as dataframe to a column.

Comment: Thank you very much I understand your point. It is an interesting solution.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what the built-in pandas `loc` is made for.

```py
df['C'] = 'foobar'
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Yes') & (df['B'] == 'Red'), 'C'] = 'bar'
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Yes') & (df['B'] == 'Blue'), 'C'] = 'foo'
```

Comment: better save `df['A'] == 'Yes'` as mask to avoid computing it twice

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, I used `.loc` attribute a lot but never thought I could make use of it like this. It is interesting that we could also put the name of the new column `C` in the bracket.

Comment: @mozway Would you please specify what it means to save and expression as mask?

Comment: something like `mask = df['A'] == 'Yes'`, then `df.loc[mask & (df['B'] == 'Red'), 'C'] = ...`

Comment: @mozway You mean assign it to a name and then use it as many times as required. Thank you very much it was a very nice suggestion.